# JQuery - Clearing and resetting predefined field input data on focus and blur

Tags: jquery, focus

I haven't really found a great way to do this yet, so I figured I'd ask here - I have an text input search form field with a predefined value (Search...). When the user focuses, I'd like to clear that value out and when they blur, it should reset the text. I've been using javascript but the method I use seems like a lot of code for not much payoff, and I also have been putting the code in the element's "onclick" handler, which I'd like to avoid, by keeping everything in jquery. If anyone has any good methods, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: I Would like to know as well!

Comment: There are many watermark plugins available. See http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/watermark or Google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, use the `placeholder` attribute for any browser that supports it.

Then, check whether the attribute is supported; if not, use this fallback:

```
$('input[placeholder]').focus(function(ev){ 
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.val() === $this.attr('placeholder')) $this.val('');
}).blur(function(ev){
  var $this = $(this);      
  if ($this.val() === '') $this.val($this.attr('placeholder'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are simply using a placeholder correct?  Why don't you look into a plugin like [jQuery Placeholder](http://webcloud.se/code/jQuery-Placeholder/).  I am using that for a project and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1) HTML5 has a placeholder attribute that essentially does the same thing. This would work in modern browsers (FF5+, Chrome, Safari, etc), but not in IE. You can do it like this:

```
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Enter a title here"/>
```

This shows some grayed out text that says "Enter a title here". When the field is focused, it removes the text, allowing the user to type.

2) You could use a simple jQuery script to do the same thing for browsers that don't support it. I recommend jQuery's Placeholder plugin (http://plugins.jquery.com/project/input-placeholder), but you can easily recreate it yourself doing something like the following:

```
    $('input[placeholder]').live('focus', function() {
        $(this).val('');
    });
    $('input[placeholder]').live('blur', function() {
        var placeholder = $(this).attr('placeholder');
        $(this).val(placeholder);
    });
```

That should work, either as-is or with slight modifications.

Good luck. :)

Comment: This is a better blur function `function(ev){
            if ($(this).val() == ""){
                $(this).val(lastVal);
            } else { 
                $(this).unbind('focus');
            }
        }` You really only want to clear the contents if they are unchanged from the placeholder.

Comment: Nice - didn't know about the placeholder attribute! Did notice a few things - one, it sets a predefined color for the text, and two, the font alignment doesn't quite match up with the regular inputted text, but I'm guessing that stuff can be adjusted with CSS

Comment: Yeah, you can change that stuff with CSS. :) And that's a good one, Mathletics! I just wrote mine off the top of my head, and I'd probably do something a lot closer to yours if I were writing my own. Good one.

Answer (score 0):

```
//run code on document.ready event
jQuery(function ($) {
    //bind event handlers to the `focus` and `blur` events for a form input
    $('#id_of_text_input').bind('focus', function () {
        //cache this form input for speedier manipulations
        var $this = $(this);
        //if the value of this text input is the placeholder, then make it's value blank
        if ($this.val() == 'Search...') {
            $this.val('');
        }
    }).bind('blur', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        //if the value of this text input is blank then make it the placeholder text
        if ($this.val() == '') {
            $this.val('Search...');
        }
    });
});
```

This will remove the placeholder if it is the only text in the input on focus and it will add the placeholder if there is no text entered in the input on blur.

Comment: Works great. I've never seen that caching method before. What's the difference between using: "$this" and just using "this" (or, to make things clearer, using something like "var $searchVar" and "var searchVar", which is what I'm accustomed to. Anything?

Comment: I added the dollar sign to the beginning of the variable so I can tell that it is a jQuery object just by looking at the variable name. And since there is a chance that the selector "$(this)" will have to be used more than once it will speed up the function to cache the selector.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function(){
        var txt = 'Please write something';
        if($(':input#mytxtbox').val()==''){
            $(':input#mytxtbox').val(txt);
        }

        $(':input#mytxtbox').blur(function(){
            if($(this).val() == ''){
                $(this).val(txt);
            }

        }).focus(function(){
            if($(this).val() == txt){
                $(this).val('');
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<input id="mytxtbox" type="text" name="xyz" value=""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as presentation goes the answer by mathletics is valid. However has anyone thought of the implications when this value gets submitted?

This jQuery plugin is a great solution as it deals with both presentation and the practicality of a functioning search form: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-placeholder-js/

That is unless you want people to search for the term 'placeholder', however I can't see any usability benefits there ;)